# DB2 referential constraint cannot created

Tags: db2, constraints

I can not add a referential constraint, both tables has the two columns id and version as primary key. I will only check the integrity that the row is existing without checking version.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEE
(ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
VERSION INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID , VERSION);

CREATE TABLE CHAIR
(ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
VERSION INTEGER NOT NULL,
ID_TABLEE INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (ID , VERSION);

ALTER Chair
ADD constraint MYC FOREIGN KEY (ID)
REFERENCES TABLEE (ID)
ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

Got this error

```
[Code: -573, SQL State: 42890]  A column list specified in the references clause of constraint "MYC " does not identify a unique constraint of the parent table or nickname "TABLEE".. SQLCODE=-573, SQLSTATE=42890, DRIVER=4.28.11
```

The problem here is that Tablee its primary key consists of two columns id and version. But the integrity check should only be made on the referenced id, not version.

Comment: it says there is no primary or unique constraint on TABLEE with column ID (and column ID only)

Comment: Yes but how can I create a constraint onone column of table which is not the primary key.

Comment: You have to set ID as primary key of TABLEE and add the FK with `FOREIGN KEY (TABLEE_ID)
REFERENCES TABLEE (ID)`. If you can't/don't want to then edit you question and give more info. Also please don't post images when you can post text.

Comment: Are VERSION columns meant to implement optimistic locking ? Then these should not be in primary keys. He DB2 will let you insert more than one TABLEE with the same ID

Comment: Not for optimistic logging, this has a special meaning in conext where it is used.

Comment: Can you explain how version is used ?

Comment: In my case, I have more columns than listed here. The version is an indicator for the validity of the entry.

Comment: If you have multiple version of the same ID in your table, then you can't add a FK that references ID since it is not unique. Maybe what you want to do can be with [system versionning](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=tables-system-period-temporal)

Answer (score 0):

To establish a foreign key on a table the referenced column needs to:

1. Be a primary key on the other table.
2. ...or at least *act* as one.

Since you already have a primary key on the referenced table, you can use the second approach and add a `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL` constraints on `ID`.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEE (
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  VERSION INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID , VERSION),
  constraint uq1 unique (id) -- added UNIQUE constraint on ID
);

CREATE TABLE CHAIR (
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  VERSION INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ID_TABLEE INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID , VERSION)
);

ALTER table Chair
ADD constraint MYC FOREIGN KEY (ID) 
REFERENCES TABLEE (ID) 
ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MApQaiHM).

**Note**: If you want `ID` to have repeated values over the table, then `ID` is not a key, and cannot be referenced as one.